# Call a parent method with React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I tried this https://medium.com/@markgituma/passing-data-to-props-children-in-react-5399baea0356, but doesn't work for me.

```js
/**
*  Router.js
*/

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import AddExercise from './pages/AddExercise';

const Router = () => (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/add-exercise" component={AddExercise} />
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;

/**
*  Layout.js
*/

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                testFunc: () => console.log('test function')
            });
        });
        return (
          <div>{ children }</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout;

/**
*  AddExercise.js
*/

const AddExercise = ({ testFunc }) => (
  <button onClick={testFunc}>Custom Btn</button>
);

export default AddExercise;
```

When I click the button in AddExercise.js nothing happened. May be is because I’m trying to use it with react-router-dom? There is any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone! Works nice doing this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/add-exercise" render={(props) => <AddExercise {...props}  testFunc={testFunc}/>} />
</Switch>
```

But looks a little dirty, because I have more than one Route (much more). So I tried with the Context API, and was perfect. I did not have to restructure my components.

AppContext.js

```
const AppContext = React.createContext({});

export const AppProvider = AppContext.Provider;
export const AppConsumer = AppContext.Consumer;
```

Layout.js

```
import { AppProvider } from './AppContext';

class Layout extends React.Component {

    testFunc = () => console.log('test function');

    render() {
        return (
            <AppProvider value={this.testFunc}> // just wrap it with the AppProvider here and send the method
                    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
            </AppProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

AddExercise.js

```
import {AppConsumer} from './AppContext';

class AddExercise extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.props.testFunc}>Custom Btn</button>
        );
    }    
}

export default props => ( // this is the weird part, but works
    <AppConsumer>
      {context => <AddExercise {...props} testFunc={context} />}
    </AppConsumer>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that, when you try to pass `testFunc` to the children using `cloneElement`, its passed as a prop to Switch Component which in your case is the child or Layout Component. And switch component does nothing with this prop and it is not passed to `AddExercise` component.

The best way to handle your case is to avoid `cloneElement` and use The Route directly in Layout Component

```
/**
*  Router.js
*/

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import AddExercise from './pages/AddExercise';

const Router = () => (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route component={Layout} /> // This is needed so that Layout gets the Router props
        </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;

/**
*  Layout.js
*/

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/add-exercise" render={(props) => <AddExercise {...props} testFunc: () => console.log('test function')/>} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout;

/**
*  AddExercise.js
*/

const AddExercise = ({ testFunc }) => (
  <button onClick={testFunc}>Custom Btn</button>
);

export default AddExercise;
```

Other solution that doesn't involve writing the Routes in Layout will include creation of another component that contains Routes like

```
  <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
            <ChildRoutes />
        </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

ChildRoutes.js

```
export const ChildRoutes = ({ testFunc }) => {
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/add-exercise" render={(props) => <AddExercise {...props}  testFunc={testFunc}/>} />
    </Switch>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We should combine the Layouts to a single component as mentioned in the [link](https://medium.com/@markgituma/passing-data-to-props-children-in-react-5399baea0356) you shared. You can try creating a new component, say for example 'FullLayout' which includes both Layout and AddExercise components.

```
/**
FullLayout.js
*/

import React from 'react'
import Layout from './Layout'
import AddExercise from '../pages/AddExercise'

class FullLayout extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
        <Layout>
            <AddExercise></AddExercise>
            <AddExercise></AddExercise>
        </Layout>
        );        
    }
}

export default FullLayout
```

Then you just have to modify the component to FullLayout in Router.js

```
<Route path="/add-exercise" component={FullLayout} />
```

This should solve the issue